# Windows 7 edition from serial?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, license-key, serial-number

I have a product key from a Windows Checked build that I'd like to use on a Free version, but the source didn't state the edition the key is bound to. So I don't know what edition should I install.

Comment: there are PID checker tools which use the **pidgenx.dll** to display the edition for your key. do a short google search.

Comment: yeah at the end I used an online one at http://d-fault.nl
I just hope it wasn't a scam... the key activated right, at least for now.

Comment: I wouldn't put my keys to a online service.

Comment: I did get it trough Dreamspark, so it wouldn't really be a problem. I did because I only foundd that website.

Comment: yeah, but this is your legal key. No one knows if this service stores the provided keys and if the people behind it sell the collected keys...

Comment: You are right. Do you know what could possibly happen in this case? They sell the key but it is already activated and bound to my PC, so it would not activate on others, am I right?